# Undo/Change Started Bounty

Tags: feature-request, support

Is it possible to Undo / Change the Started Bounty like

If Need to change the Bounty offered

If need to cancel the Started Bounty

and

What will happen if a bounty question never answered

Comment: Please do not remove the duplicate link when editing a question.

Comment: I don't see why this question got downvoted.  It's obviously very well asked.  It's the first thing that shows up when you search for "how to change bounty", and any other questions should be merged with it and deleted.  Even though it has a downvote, the specific language, and the directness of the question pull it right to the top of the list.  I'd vote it up, but I have -15 rep because the people at meta stackoverflow are chronically addicted downvoting pricks.

Comment: @Diago P.S. - Your comment is a duplicate.  You should delete it.  It's just useless fluff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for bounty you will find the following [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: To be specific: "Can I cancel my bounty?

No. Once started, you cannot cancel a bounty.

If you feel there are exceptional circumstances, flag the question for moderator attention to explain the situation."

Comment: Why don't you include the data instead of adding an external link.  What are you going to do if the link dies?  Now I just have to go to another page to get the answer.  Also, I have to browse through the page.  It's a monsterous faq, and it's going to take an hour.  Not nearly as useful as a searchable question like this, which could just give me the answer.  Was this post useful? (clicks no)